# How do I shutdown a Quartz ThreadGroup?

Tags: java, multithreading, quartz-scheduler

How can I stop these threads :  **Group[QuartzScheduler:DefaultQuartzScheduler:class java.lang.ThreadGroup]** ?

I have an object **ThreadGroup** that contains it, but what is the correct way to destroy it?

Answer (score 0):

You must invoke `Scheduler.shutdown();`